# 8-5 One hour unpaid

Tags: canada, break-time

I signed a contract stating that I will be working 8am-5pm with one hour unpaid lunch. No where in my contract states that I get breaks or any paid break through out the day.

Are they able to do this?

I've tried to look it up on the website but it's a little confusing to understand, I live in Manitoba, Canada.
I get paid per hour also...

My day looks like 8am-12:30pm

Lunch 12:30-1:30 unpaid

1:30pm-5pm

Comment: Why do you think they are unable to do this?

Comment: Regarding the "legal advice" close vote.  Guidelines on that reason state *Questions should be able to be answered by an HR professional in another company, and shouldn't require specific legal expertise* any Canadian HR person should be able to easily answer this.

Comment: In my experience lunch is virtually always unpaid, why would you think otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

They seem within their rights under this scheme.

> What are the mandatory food and rest breaks for employees?
>
> Employees must receive a 30 minute unpaid break after every five hours
>   of work. This is the only break required by the Employment Standards
>   Code. Many workplaces provide coffee breaks or other meal breaks, but
>   they are at the employer's discretion.

http://www.cfib-fcei.ca/english/article/892-employment-regulations-in-manitoba.html

> Employees must be given a 30 minute unpaid break after every five
>   consecutive hours of work.  Many employers provide additional coffee
>   breaks, cigarette breaks or other meal breaks. These are a benefit,
>   but are not required.

http://www.gov.mb.ca/labour/standards/doc,hours-and-breaks,factsheet.html